# Unable to install snap store or spotify

Tags: snap

I have tried installing snap store or any other snap packages but i keep getting an error : error: cannot perform the following tasks:

- Mount snap “snap-store” (558) (snap “snap-store” assumes unsupported
  features: snapd2.43 (try to update snapd and refresh the core snap))

---

I’ve tried to both remove snap a reinstall it, I have tried updating snap and everything seems to be fine and yet it will still not install snap packages.

snap version:

1. snap 2.37.4-1+b1
2. snapd 2.37.4-1+b1
3. series 16
4. deepin 20.3
5. kernel 5.10.60-amd64-desktop

Comment: What command did you use to install snap?

Comment: sudo snap install

Comment: This question has already been asked and answered on https://askubuntu.com/a/1385139 . I am not sure what is expected, when the answer provided there is absolutely accurate.

Comment: the answer to that didn' help just gavd the same error again and again